# Find $\log_{7}\sqrt[3]{xy} $ in terms of $p$ and $q$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given that $\log_{7}x^2y=p$ and $\log_{7}xy^2=q$, find $\log_{7}\sqrt[3]{xy} $ in terms of $p$ and $q$.

So I started in this way:

$\log_{7}x^2y=p$ = (Using $\log_{a}y=x$ can be written as $y=a^x$, we get,) $x=\sqrt\frac{7^p}{y}$

Again, $\log_{7}xy^2 = q$, we write it as $y=\sqrt\frac{7^q}{x}$

We got values of $x$ and $y$, we have to substitute them into $\log_{7}\sqrt[3]{xy}$

Right? How do I solve it next? I mean how to do this: $\log_{7}\sqrt[3]{{\sqrt\frac{7^9}{y}}{\sqrt\frac{7^q}{x}}}$

Or else I should substitute the value of $x$ in $y$? Anyways, how to solve this root over complicated problems?

Comment: Hints: $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b), \log(a^b)=b\log(a)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular problem is fairly easy to solve:  $p=\log_7(x^2y)$ and $q=\log_7(xy^2)$ together imply

$$p+q=\log_7(x^2y)+\log_7(xy^2)=\log_7(x^3y^3)=3\log_7(xy)$$

Therefore

$$\log_7\sqrt[3]{xy}={1\over3}\log_7(xy)={1\over9}(p+q)$$

Note that the "$7$" plays no significant role here.  The simplicity (here) depends only the particular powers of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

As $\displaystyle\log_a(b^m)=m\log_ab$ where both logarithms remain defined

and $\displaystyle\log a+\log b=\log ab,$

$$\log_7(x^2y)+\log_7(xy^2)=\log_7(xy)^3=3\log_7(xy)$$

So, $$\log_7(xy)^{\dfrac13}=?$$

Comment: Okay, I understood this: $\log_7(x^2y)+\log_7(xy^2)=\log_7(xy)^3=3\log_7(xy)$ but after that?

Comment: @Kiara, can you apply the formula in the first line on the last line of the answer?

Comment: Yeah, got it! Let me try! @labbhattacharjee